# Kindle Fire first-generation inputType "numberSigned" and "numberDecimal" cancel each other out

Tags: android-layout, input, numbers, kindle-fire

I have a calculator-type app in the store that has some editText boxes that only allow numbers, decimals, and negative numbers.

I put in the XML `android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"`.

This worked great for every device I tested it on, except I just got a email from someone using a Kindle Fire first-generation saying that they can't input a decimal or negative number because  `.` and `-` are greyed out.

I set up a Kindle Fire first-generation emulator in Eclipse and started playing around, and sure enough I found the following:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
android:inputType="number|numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

which caused both `.` and `-` to be greyed out.

`numberDecimal` and `numberSigned` both work fine when they are only paired with "number" but not each other.

Does anyone know how to make `numberDecimal|numberSigned` work together, or make a editText only allow numbers, decimals, and negative versions of the two former on the Kindle Fire first-generation?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputType="number|numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```